# JavaScript heap out of memory when deploying to heroku - Nestjs Application API request for AWS S3 delete object

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, heroku, amazon-s3, nestjs

NPM Module: "@ntegral/nestjs-s3": "^1.0.2",

Rest API Application: Nest js

Code for service which is giving error when deploying to Heroku

```
async deleteImage(filename: string): Promise<{message: string}> {
        if(filename !== undefined || filename !== null) {
            const param = {
                Bucket: 'myblogbucket1',
                Key: `authorProfile/${filename}` 
            }
            this.s3.deleteObject(param)
            return {message: `deleted ${filename}`};
        }
```

And the controller which handle this code:

```
@Delete('/deletefile/:filename')
    async deleteOldImage(
        @Param('filename') filename: string
    ): Promise<{message: string}> {
        return this.profileService.deleteImage(filename)
    }
```

And here's the module imports settings in profile module inside Nestjs Application

```
S3Module.forRoot({
      accessKeyId: process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID,
      secretAccessKey: process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY
    }),
```

Once I build this App using

```
npm run start:dev
```

This works fine, when I hit this through postman to server. In AWS S3 bucket, file is getting deleted.

Something like:

```
http://localhost:3000/profile/deletefile/131bc7c5-d6e3-4cdf-bdf7-b55448a0f14f.jpeg
```

But when I try to push this code to heroku it give build error.

Here's the stack

```
<--- Last few GCs --->
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064905+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064908+00:00 app[web.1]: [58:0x342e9e0]    12037 ms: Mark-sweep 255.5 (257.0) -> 255.0 (257.3) MB, 331.4 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.138, current mu = 0.027) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064908+00:00 app[web.1]: [58:0x342e9e0]    12517 ms: Mark-sweep 255.6 (257.3) -> 255.2 (257.8) MB, 469.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.071, current mu = 0.022) allocation failure scavenge might not succeed
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064909+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064909+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064909+00:00 app[web.1]: <--- JS stacktrace --->
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064909+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064910+00:00 app[web.1]: ==== JS stack trace =========================================
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064910+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064911+00:00 app[web.1]: 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x13c5b79]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064911+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: StubFrame [pc: 0x134ca01]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064912+00:00 app[web.1]: Security context: 0x0a541a0408d1 <JSObject>
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064913+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: parseStatement(aka parseStatement) [0x26ae695381c1] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:~23390] [pc=0x33711f1a8be3](this=0x1040d0c004b1 <undefined>)
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064914+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: parseList(aka parseList) [0x26ae69535141] [/app/node_modules/typescript/lib/typescript.js:~20041] [pc=0x33711f1be0c0](this=0x1040d0c004b1 <undefined>,1,0x26a...
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064914+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.064921+00:00 app[web.1]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory        
2020-04-30T12:08:43.065228+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078709+00:00 app[web.1]: Writing Node.js report to file: report.20200430.120843.58.0.001.json
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078710+00:00 app[web.1]: Node.js report completed
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078711+00:00 app[web.1]: 1: 0xa09830 node::Abort() [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078711+00:00 app[web.1]: 2: 0xa09c55 node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078712+00:00 app[web.1]: 3: 0xb7d71e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078713+00:00 app[web.1]: 4: 0xb7da99 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078713+00:00 app[web.1]: 5: 0xd2a1f5  [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.078713+00:00 app[web.1]: 6: 0xd2a886 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.081317+00:00 app[web.1]: 7: 0xd37105 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.081318+00:00 app[web.1]: 8: 0xd37fb5 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.081319+00:00 app[web.1]: 9: 0xd3aa6c v8::internal::Heap::AllocateRawWithRetryOrFail(int, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin, v8::internal::AllocationAlignment) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.081320+00:00 app[web.1]: 10: 0xd0163b v8::internal::Factory::NewFillerObject(int, bool, v8::internal::AllocationType, v8::internal::AllocationOrigin) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.081320+00:00 app[web.1]: 11: 0x104300e v8::internal::Runtime_AllocateInYoungGeneration(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.082018+00:00 app[web.1]: 12: 0x13c5b79  [node]
2020-04-30T12:08:43.174500+00:00 app[web.1]: Aborted
```

Now once I delete this service method and controller, deployment goes successfully. This means its not the error related to Heroku Dyno or memory limits. My App is also only 58 Mb and I have 512 with me.

After searching for 2 days I found that there is some kind of infinite loop is going on in my method and because of that this build is getting crashed when deploying to heroku. As it says JavaScript heap out of memory. But I am not able to find the issue since this working fine when I start this application on localhost:3000. and also I am new to backend.

Can anyone correct this code so it can also deploy without error and run on Heroku. Remember this code is running on local-host without any issue and App is also getting build on my PC.

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happened with me:

1. app works well on local
2. when deploying to Heroku (hobby dyno - 512Mb RAM) it crashes with OOM issue

Basically the trouble you're having that on startup your app will use more memory than once it is running. In my case I had to remove an npm package so that it manages to get through the startup.

As I see you have one of several choices:

- setup heroku to only install [prod dependencies](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support#only-installing-dependencies) - `heroku config:set NPM_CONFIG_PRODUCTION=true`
- try to reduce on the number of 3rd party package dependencies
- get a dyno with larger memory allowance
- *perhaps* try dockerizing your app and deploy the image to heroku - with in the docker build steps you can do some optimizations e.g. `npm dedupe` - but I'm not sure this will actually help